# Why Likelihood function not exactly maximized at the obtained estimate? (R code provided)

Tags: distributions, bayesian, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, likelihood-ratio

**Background:**

Suppose I have a parameter called "**$d$**" that is linearly related to the non-centrality parameter ($ncp$) of a $t~distribution$. Specifically,

(1)              $ncp = d\sqrt(n)$. And since the $ncp$ here basically is a $t$ variate, in general:

(2)              $d = \frac{t}{\sqrt(n)}$. (where $n$ is sample size).

Equation (1) above helps in making a **"likelihood function"** for parameter "$d$". That is, given an obtained (and fixed) estimate of "$d$", one can convert the $d$ based on (1) to a $ncp$ and then let the $d$ in (1) vary (**see R code below**). The result is shown in the below image (**R code is below the image**):

[image]

### Question:

I'm (deeply) wondering **why the "mode" of the likelihood function "DOES NOT" exactly match the single "observed estimate of d"**?

**P.S.** In the R code below, if you change the "observed t-value" to something else, you'll see that ALWAYS the "observed estimate of d" is smaller than the mode of the likelihood function!

**Here is the R code:**

```
##### Observed Data needed to obtain an estimate of "d" #####

N = 10                 # Sample size
df = N - 1             # degrees of freedom
t = 4                  # observed t-value, this is going to be FIXED in for "d"
observed.d = t/sqrt(N) # Using Eq.(2): Observed and the only one estimate of "d"

#### Likelihood function:####

par(mar = c(5.1, 6.1, 4.1, 2.1) )

Likelihood = curve( dt(t, df, ncp = x*sqrt(N) ), ## "x" represents "d" which is varying
                col = 'red4', lwd = 3, from = -4, to = 4, n = 1e4, 
                ylab = "L(d)",xlab = "d", cex.lab = 2)$y   


abline(v = observed.d, lty = 3, lwd = 2)

text(observed.d, max(Likelihood)/2, "Observed d", srt = 90, pos = 3, cex = 1.6, font = 2)
```

Comment: Because the mode of the non-central t-distribution is not exactly the non-centrality parameter, cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution#Mode

Comment: @Elvis, thanks. so, is my function above then the correct "likelihood function" for parameter "d" or not ?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. When df is large, the mode and the non-centrality parameter are very close to each other.

Comment: @Elvis, so the maximum likelihood estimate of parameter "d" is the "observed d" (which is a bit smaller than the mode) OR the actual "mode" of the likelihood function?

Comment: The MLE is the mode of the likelihood function, by definition...

Comment: And I don't know what your "observed d" is, actually? How do you obtain this?

Comment: @Elvis, "observed d" (please also see my R code), is an "effect size" (some call it Cohen's d). Basically, $d = mean/sd$ (standardized mean)? Is the nature of $d$ here important?

Comment: From the WP page I get that with an observation with $df = \nu = 9$, the moment estimate of the ncp parameter it $ncp = t / \sqrt{9/2} \Gamma(8/2)/\Gamma(9/2)$ that is here $3.655$, leading $d = ncp / \sqrt(N) = 1.16$.

This seems reasonable, as `mean( rt(1e4, df = 9 , ncp = 3.655) )` is `4.00`.

Comment: @Elvis, I see, So, what conclusion should we be drawing regarding our case here?

Comment: I suggest you to draw random values from a $t$-distribution with `rt` to estimate the precision of your estimators. From what we see here I suspect that both your estimate by $ncp = t$ and the MLE are biased. What you are asking is unclear, if your question is "how to estimate the ncp from a single draw from a non-central t distribution", you should edit your text to make it clear....

Comment: @Elvis, Great thank you! Let me take care of a few things and come back here in about 2 hours to follow up.

Comment: @Elvis, are you there Elvis? I'm still thinking what would be the correct unbiased MLE for $d$?

Comment: The MLE is the max of the density function, but it is not unbiased. It is only asymptotically unbiased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently you are looking for an estimate of the ncp. Your idea was to estimate it directly by the observed value. Let's compare this estimate, the moment estimate obtained using the expected value of the distribution, and the MLE.

```
> N <- 1e5 
> ncp <- 4
> df <- 9
> # sample of N elements in t(df = 9, ncp = 4)
> x <- rt(N, df = df, ncp = ncp)

> # moment estimate of the ncp
> ME <- x / (sqrt(df/2)*gamma((df-1)/2)/gamma(df/2))

> # Max Likelihood
> MLE <- sapply(x, function(x) optimize(function(d) dt(x, df = df, ncp = d), c(0, 50), maximum = TRUE )$maximum)
```

Mean and variance of your estimate.

```
> mean(x)
[1] 4.380576
> var(x)
[1] 2.693727
```

Of the Moment Estimate.

```
> mean(ME)
[1] 4.003298
> var(ME)
[1] 2.249712
```

Of the MLE.

```
> mean(MLE)
[1] 4.439314
> var(MLE)
[1] 2.775269
```

I leave it to you to draw your conclusions and to try with other values of ncp and df.